# When trying to get dynamically created UILabel to wrap, text disappears

Tags: xcode, swift, word-wrap, cgrect, sizetofit

I'm trying to display some description text that varies from a couple of words to a hundred words. I've set my UILabel to wrap to compensate using the code below

```
    descText.frame = CGRect(x: 115, y: 160, width: 465, height: 21)     
    descText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
    descText.numberOfLines = 0
    descText.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    descText.sizeToFit()
    descText.Text = text
    dtlView.addSubview(descText)
```

If I remove descText.sizeToFit() the text reappears but won't wrap, the same happens if I try to set height in CGRect to CGFloat.max.

What am I missing?

Comment: First assign `text` and then call `sizeToFit()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the position of sizeToFit() after assigning text did the job as suggested by Bartlomiej above

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `ByCharWrapping` instead of  using `ByWordWrapping`

Also make sure to call `sizeToFit()` only after assigning the text.

```
descText.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByCharWrapping
descText.Text = text
descText.sizeToFit()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately it still wouldn't wrap but changing the position of sizeToFit() did the trick